# How to search indexed nodes in neo4j

Tags: lucene, neo4j

I am indexing the neo4 nodes like this

```
BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider( db );
logger.info("indexer created :" + indexProvider);
BatchInserterIndex nodeIndexer = indexProvider.nodeIndex( "actors", MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
nodeIndexer.setCacheCapacity( "name", 100000 );
long indexId = db.createNode(map);
nodeIndexer.add( indexId, map );
```

while searching the nodes, i am able to search with one key, but i would like to search in all keys.

```
List<Node> nodesList = new ArrayList<Node>();
IndexManager manager = graphDatabaseService.index();
org.neo4j.graphdb.index.Index<Node> nodesIndex = manager.forNodes("actors");
IndexHits<Node> nodes = nodesIndex.query("Associate_Name:*" + pattern + "*");
Node aNode = null;
while (nodes.hasNext()) {
    nodesList.add(nodes.next());
}

return nodesList;
```

i tried with `IndexHits<Node> nodes = nodesIndex.query("*:*"+pattern+"*");` but this dint work.

Any body can tell me how to search indexed nodes in neo4j with all the keys.

Edit :With one key Associate_Name searching --> If the given pattern exists in Associate_Name key, then those many Nodes will be returned.

But i would like to search whether the given pattern exists in any of the Key of particular Node, do this search to all the nodes, which of the nodes are containing the given pattern in any value those should return.

Thanks for the suggestion but my requirement will fulfill with OR like this

```
nodesIndex.query("kye1:"+pattern1+" OR key2:"+pattern2+" OR key3_part:"+pattern3_part+"* ")
```

is this good way to search the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean 'with all the keys'? Do you mean you'd like to get all nodes associated with a key, or all nodes in an index?

To search for all nodes associated with a key: `nodesIndex.query("Associate_Name:*")`

To search for all nodes in an index: `nodesIndex.query("*:*")`

Comment: and in case you are looking for all keys on a node: `nodesIndex.query("kye1:"+pattern1+" AND key2:"+pattern2+" AND key3_part:"+pattern3_part+"* ")`

Comment: I think what he means is he wants to search EVERY key for the same pattern, but he doesn't want to have to specify every key individually. So if his node has five properties, he wants to specify something like `query("*:*mySearchpattern*")` and have `*mySearchPattern*` be checked against all five of those properties.